# Should it be "three-fourths" or "three-fourth"?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I'm having some confusion expressing the form of fraction in this sentence. In this sentence should I use "three-fourths" or "three-fourth"?

> To the amazement of three-fourths of the band, their controlling manager was back in their lives.

Comment: Now I'm curious why the fourth member was not amazed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is plural, because there are three of them: three-**fourths**.  If it had been only one, it would be singular ("one-fourth of the band").

Comment: It helps to remember that the compound word complicates the issue.  We have a noun, "fourth."  The noun means "one quarter of something."  However, though a noun, the word "fourth" (and all the numeric words like it, e.g., "third," "tenth," etc.) always acts as a [noun-adjective](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/noun_adjective), meaning is modifies another noun (implicitly or explicitly).  Thus, just as we would say, "I have two cars in my garage," we would say "I have three-fourths of an apple" ("fourths" modifies "apple" and we have three of them).

Answer (score -1):

"Three-fourths of the house have been completed," is the right answer. "Three-fourths of the house has been completed is wrong".

Comment: Can you explain why you believe this is the answer?

Comment: I disagree with this answer. "Three fourths of the house" is a single thing, it is not as if there were four separate sections that were to be built separately. Therefore  "Three-fourths of the house has been completed" is correct, and "Three-fourths of the house have been completed." is wrong, or at best awkward, old-fashioned, and pedantic